# Information about HTTPS

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I do have a website that has an SSL certificate installed when I visit the website I see the look icon like this :

[image]

But in some other websites I see the full company description right after the look icon like below :

[image]

So my question is : is there a special config that I need to do to my SSL certificate to be able to show my company name after the look icon?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you only have to buy the most expensive certificate.

Comment: Can I have more details please?

Answer (score 0):

These are [two different types of SSL certificates](https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2013/11/ssl-certificate-types/)

The first one is either a DV (domain-validated) or an OV (organization-validated). Only the EV (extensive validation) certificate results in the naming of entity being displayed in the browser.

EV certificates are generally more expensive (because of the more detailed validation process) and they requires more time to be issued.

It is worth to mention that, from an encryption point of view, all these 3 tyoes of certificates provide the same level of security.